# How to compare two very large strings

Tags: php, string, compare

How can I compare the two large strings of size 50Kb each using php. I want to highlight the differentiating bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to output like `diff`?

Perhaps this is what you want https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/5bfe1d2a8f967c7901ace50f04ac2d9308ed3169/simplediff.php

ADDED:

Or if you want to highlight every character that is different, you can use a PHP script like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string1);$i++){
    if($string1[$i]!=$string2[$i]){
        echo "Char $i is different ({$string1[$i]}!={$string2[$i]}<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Perhaps if you can tell us in detail how you would like to compare, or give us some examples, it would be easier for us to decide the answer.

Comment: I want to higligh each bit that is different from the other

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman Perhaps give us more detail

Answer (score 4):

Differences between two strings can also be found using XOR:

```
$s = 'the sky is falling';
$t = 'the pie is failing';
$d = $s ^ $t;

echo $s, "\n";
for ($i = 0, $n = strlen($d); $i != $n; ++$i) {
        echo $d[$i] === "\0" ? ' ' : '#';
}
echo "\n$t\n";
```

Output:

```
the sky is falling
    ###      #
the pie is failing
```

The XOR operation will result in a string that has `'\0'` where both strings are the same and something not `'\0'` if they're different. It won't be faster than just comparing both strings character by character, but it'd be useful if you want to just know the first character that's different by using `strspn()`.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to @Alvin's script:

I tested it in my local server with a 50kb lorem ipsum string, i substituted all "a" to "4" and it highlight them. It runs pretty fast

```
    <?php
$string1 = "This is a sample text to test a script to highlight the differences between 2 strings, so the second string will be slightly different";
$string2 = "This is 2 s4mple text to test a scr1pt to highlight the differences between 2 strings, so the first string will be slightly different";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string1);$i++){                 
        if($string1[$i]!=$string2[$i]){
            $string3[$i] = "<mark>{$string1[$i]}</mark>";
            $string4[$i] = "<mark>{$string2[$i]}</mark>";
        }
        else {
            $string3[$i] = "{$string1[$i]}";
            $string4[$i] = "{$string2[$i]}";    
        }
    }
    $string3 = implode("",$string3);
    $string4 = implode("",$string4);

    echo "$string3". "<br />". $string4;
?>
```